# Invoice Id return with null after change using Stripe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

After I charge for specific subscribed customer on stripe object return with Invoice Id null,Do you know how can I fix It ?
or how can I create invoice for specific payment ?
I know how to create invoice using API but I didn't find way to create invoice for one time payment using API.
If stripe not support creating invoices for this type why they return Invoice Id including in charge object after charging. 
That's my code to charge :

```
       var myCharge = new ChargeCreateOptions();
        myCharge.Amount = (Int32)(amount * 100);
        myCharge.Currency = "usd";
        myCharge.ReceiptEmail = "email@domain.com";
        myCharge.Description = "Upgrade client";
        myCharge.CustomerId = customer.SubscripedClientId;
        myCharge.Capture = true;
        var chargeService = new ChargeService(stripesecretkey);
        Charge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
```

after charge done stripecharge object include invoice id with null value

Answer (score 0):

To create an invoice for a one-time payment, you need to first [create line items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) through the api and then [create the invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoice). The invoice will collect any open line items and attach them to itself.

Comment: Yes we can create invoice and collect it from customer , but my question about how to create invoice for specific charge ,,,,,, cuz After I charged I found invoice number is null

Comment: You can pay the invoice to associate a charge with an invoice.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice