# Invoicer PDF gives null but Membership does not give PDF null

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

My problem as it is right now. It is that I must have made such that a customer can buy an item that is only paid once. Thus assigned Invoice id and PDf to the database.

As it is right now I only get hold of Invoice id while PDF is null.

I've read a little more about this.
[Invoice Id return with null after change using Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934041/invoice-id-return-with-null-after-change-using-stripe)

```
var options = new ProductCreateOptions
{
    Name = "Starter Setup",
};

var service = new ProductService();
var product = service.Create(options);

var optionsA = new PriceCreateOptions
{
    Product = product.Id,
    UnitAmount = 2000,
    Currency = "usd",
};

var serviceA = new PriceService();
var price = serviceA.Create(optionsA);

var optionsB = new CustomerCreateOptions
{
    Email = model.Mail,
    Name = model.FuldName,
    Source = token
};

var serviceB = new CustomerService();
var customer = serviceB.Create(optionsB);

var optionsC = new InvoiceItemCreateOptions
{
    Customer = customer.Id,
    Price = price.Id,
};

var serviceC = new InvoiceItemService();
var invoiceItem = serviceC.Create(optionsC);

var invoiceId = invoiceItem.Id;

var serviceE = new InvoiceService();
var f = serviceE.Get(invoiceId);

var pdf = f.InvoicePdf;// This here gives zero.
```

If I do it this way, I'll get this out of it. I get the Invoice ID that I want here but I get nothing on the invoice that shows that it is zero.

```
{
"id": "ii_1IR4UtFnB7TvDVRrzPwWo8ZW",
  "object": "invoiceitem",
  "amount": 2000,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": "cus_J3Aqpyt4PwqCcN",
  "date": 1614815575,
  "description": "Starter Setup",
  "discountable": true,
  "discounts": [
  ],
  "invoice": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
....
}
```

With this, my thinking is whether I will in a way be able to make such that I make a membership which then stops immediately but that it says in the invoice that the purchase is only of a single item and not several months.

The way I have done it in relation to membership I have done like this.

```
var createCustomer = new CustomerCreateOptions
{
    Source = token,
    Name = model.FuldName,
    Email = model.Mail
};

var addService = new CustomerService();
var customer = addService.Create(createCustomer);

var optionsProduct = new ProductCreateOptions
{
    Name = $"Single buy - {DateTime.Now} - Kursus Id : {id}",
    Type = "service",
};
var serviceProduct = new ProductService();
Product product = serviceProduct.Create(optionsProduct);

var optionsPlan = new PlanCreateOptions
{
    Currency = "dkk",
    Interval = Helpers.Stripe.interval,
    Nickname =
        $"Single buy - {DateTime.Now} - Kursus Id : {id}",
    Amount = amount,
    Product = product.Id,
    IntervalCount = 1
};
var servicePlan = new PlanService();
Plan plan = servicePlan.Create(optionsPlan);

var items = new List<SubscriptionItemOptions>()
{
    new SubscriptionItemOptions()
    {
        Plan = plan.Id,
        Quantity = 1
    },
};
var createSubscruptionA = new SubscriptionCreateOptions
{
    Customer = customer.Id,
    Items = items,
    OffSession = true,
};
var addserviceA = new SubscriptionService();
Subscription subscription = addserviceA.Create(createSubscruptionA);

var invoiceId = subscription.LatestInvoiceId;
var service = new InvoiceService();
var pdf = service.Get(invoiceId).InvoicePdf;
```

That which I would like to achieve by this. It is that I can get hold of PDF and Invoice id as I will use it for my system in the future etc.

**EDIT**

```
var optionsB = new CustomerCreateOptions
{
    Email = model.Mail,
    Name = model.FuldName,
    Source = token
};

var serviceB = new CustomerService();
var customer = serviceB.Create(optionsB);

var optionsC = new InvoiceItemCreateOptions
{
    Customer = customer.Id,
    Price = price.Id,
};

var serviceC = new InvoiceItemService();
var invoiceItem = serviceC.Create(optionsC);

var invoiceId = invoiceItem.Id;

var invoiceOptions = new InvoiceCreateOptions
{
    Customer = customer.Id,
    AutoAdvance = true,
};
var invoiceService = new InvoiceService();
var invoice = invoiceService.Create(invoiceOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one-off Invoices you need to create Invoice Items for the Customer (as you've done), but importantly you then need to [create an Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/create#create-invoice-code) that will contain those Items.

This line is not correct for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
var invoiceId = invoiceItem.Id;
```

Instead, you need to create the invoice as shown in the docs linked above:

```
var invoiceOptions = new InvoiceCreateOptions
{
  Customer = "cus_123",
  AutoAdvance = true,
};
var invoiceService = new InvoiceService();
var invoice = invoiceService.Create(invoiceOptions);
```

The Invoice object will have an `invoice_pdf` URL ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-invoice_pdf)) after you [finalize](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/finalize) it.

```
var service = new InvoiceService();
service.FinalizeInvoice(
  "in_123"
);
```

Comment: Okay, when I try to do what you tell me about, I get an error that says "Nothing to invoice for customer" - https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/invoice-no-customer-line-items

Comment: Yes, you need to create an invoice item first, _then_ create the invoice for the same customer.

Comment: Okay @nolan H. I have update/edit my code. So u can see what i have do. or is it me who has misunderstood how it is?

Comment: OK, and what is the result now? Is it working? If not, what happens instead?

Comment: Is the invoice item create happening successfully? Have you looked at your developer logs to see if it was successful or returned an error? https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/

Comment: U can see here what error its coming. https://i.imgur.com/O1R3aug.png

Comment: Ok that's because the `/invoices` call right before is "consuming" the invoice item created so it is correct that when you make that second call to `/invoices` there are no items left to invoice. Why/how are you calling create invoice twice? Your snippet does not show repeated calls.